# Kill process '[avconv] <defunct>'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have more than 30 process '[avconv] ' (i have a bug in script), With this command i find these process :

```
Ps aux | grep '\[avconv\] <defunct>'
```

but i don't know how to kill these process, anyone have an idea to kill these process ?

Thanks

Comment: if you kill the parent process they will dissapear. try `pstree` to figure out the parent.

Comment: related: [What is <defunct> for a process and why it doesn't get killed?](http://askubuntu.com/q/201303/3712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<defunct>` process is a process that has already terminated, and hence cannot be killed, but for which the parent has not yet invoked one of the wait system calls (`wait`, `wait3`, `wait4`, `waitpid`, etc...) to read its exit status. As a result, the process information is retained by the system in case the parent eventually does try to obtain its status. Such processes disappear when the parent reads their exit status.

These `<defunct>` processes also disappear when the parent is killed, as the `init` process will take ownership of the process and obtain (and discard) its status.

You can avoid `<defunct>` processes by ensuring you issue as many `wait` system calls as you issue `fork` calls.

Alternatively, as J.F. Sebastian points out, you can also avoid `<defunct>` processes by either setting the SIGCHLD signal disposition to SIG_IGN (ignore the signal) or by using the SA_NOCLDWAIT flag when registering a SIGCHLD signal handler (or when resetting the default disposition with SIG_DFL) using `sigaction`. In this case, however, the child's exit status will not be made available to the parent - it is simply discarded.

Comment: +1: both precise and clear explanation. There is also an extension: zombies can also be avoided by configuring signals: `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag or set `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`.

Comment: yes, absolutely... forgot about that one. will add to the answer, thx.